# Clip feature (with selected attributes) with individual polygons using iterator: name error or repetitive selection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-attribute, iterator, error-000354

I have a bunch of locations (polygons) across the USA that I will use to clip a number of features and rasters (e.g., the [National Hydrography Dataset](https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/ngp/national-hydrography/national-hydrography-dataset?qt-science_support_page_related_con=0#qt-science_support_page_related_con)). When I clip a dataset like the NHD with all of the polygon in one feature class, it takes a lot longer than if I split the polygons and clip the dataset with one polygon at a time.

To that end, using model builder, I am attempting to iterate through a directory of features (individual polygons) and use each of them to `clip` a different feature that has first been treated with `Select Layer By Attribute`. The model (below) works, but will perform `Select Layer By Attribute` for each iteration, making the process much slower than if `Select Layer By Attribute` was just performed once.

*Full model, but slow*
[image: arcmap model builder iterator]

Next, I attempted to use submodel and main model following ESRI guidance.The submodel looks like this:

*submodel to iterate through features*
[image: submodel arcmap model builder]

and the submodel within the main model looks like this:

*submodel within main model*
[image: submodel within main model]

However, this operation fails with the following error:

```
ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
Failed to execute (Clip).
```

Then I read about using `Collect Values` or `Select Data` and tried using each (separately) at the end of the submodel. This did not work.

Next, I [read](https://community.esri.com/thread/228437-inline-variable-substitution-in-modelbuilder-with-submodel) that saving the 'Name' as a parameter in the submodel, and then right click on the submodel in the main model and `Make Variable > From Parameter > Name`. However, `Make Variable > From Parameter` was unable to be selected. I don't know what changed, but one time I was allowed to  `Make Variable > From Parameter` it created `%Name%` instead of name and I tried the model with `Name` and `%Name%` but the got the same error again (000354). Even in this same model, I cannot get `Make Variable > From Parameter` to be available again.

*One example of a different model (I also tried renaming `FL_%Name%.shp` to `Output Values`)*
[image: a different submodel trial]

Then I tried using `Parse Path > Name` connected to the submodel output with `Name` connected a precondition to `Clip`, this also produced a #000354 error.

Outside of model builder I saved the feature with selected attributes as a new feature. Then I used this and model builder with an `iterator` and `clip` and it worked great and quickly.

But, I'd like to know how to make the model work for the future. How can I avoid  `ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters`? I feel like I am missing something.